# Java 3rd party libraries

Tags: java, malware

Is it possible to hide malware into a Java library? I'm learning java and i've also read many uses 3rd party libraries, but can they contain malware? Im a bit worried, because i don't wanna end up getting infected later on.

Comment: All languages use third party libraries which possibly contain malware. Use trusted download sites and common sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any file or jar can contain malware. If you are concerned, make sure you run a virus scan.

However, Maven and other dependency management servers run their own virus scans and are generally considered safe.

There is a lot of additional information on this topic in this post:
[How do we know we can trust the Maven Central Repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24967270/how-do-we-know-we-can-trust-the-maven-central-repository)

I would urge you to read it and make your own decision.

Comment: Are there any "Trusted repositories" for java libaries? Also thanks for the answer.

Comment: I updated the answer for you.

Comment: Alright, thanks! I tried upvoting but i cant yet, but thanks!